# set postgres instance as readonly with no master

Tags: postgresql

I have a pg 10 instance that I want to behave as a read only/replica/standby instance.

There is no master, only that read only database and I want the query `select pg_is_in_recovery();` to return `true` to satisfy a monitoring check.

I have tried add a `recovery.conf` file in the data dir with `standby_mode = 'on'` as content then `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` but I still get `false` to `select pg_is_in_recovery();`

```
office-accounting=# SELECT pg_read_file('recovery.conf');
    pg_read_file
---------------------
 standby_mode = 'on'+

(1 row)

office-accounting=# select pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery
-------------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a `recovery.conf` file in the data dir with `standby_mode = 'on'` as content is the right solution but `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` does not reload `recovery.conf` you must `restart` the postgres instance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't set up replication properly. The `recovery.conf` file needs something like this:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=127.0.0.1 port=5888 user=replicator password=xxx'
trigger_file = 'postgresql_xxx_12345.trigger'
```

The port should/can be a port that isn't used. The cluster will try to connect there - and fail but it will come online and allow read-only connections as if it is a slave. Which it is actually, with its imaginary master being down for the moment and indefinitely.

A side effect that you probably want to avoid - disable logging perhaps? - is that the log will be full of errors, of the streaming replication connect failures:

> 2017-12-05 22:19:08 UTC [18096-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the
> primary server: could not connect to server: Connection refused       Is
> the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting      TCP/IP
> connections on port 5888?
>
> 2017-12-05 22:19:13 UTC [18099-1] FATAL:
> could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server:
> Connection refused        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and
> accepting         TCP/IP connections on port 5888?
>
> 2017-12-05 22:19:18 UTC
> [18103-1] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not
> connect to server: Connection refused         Is the server running on host
> "127.0.0.1" and accepting         TCP/IP connections on port 5888?